# Add quotation at start and end of every other line ignoring empty line

Tags: python, regex, macos, textedit

I need help on organizing texts. I have the list of thousands vocabs in csv. There are term, definition, and sample sentence for each word. Term and definition is separated by the tab and sample sentence is separated by an empty line.

For example:

```
exacerbate  worsen

This attack will exacerbate the already tense relations between the two communities

exasperate  irritate, vex

he often exasperates his mother with pranks

execrable   very bad, abominable, utterly detestable

an execrable performance
```

I want to organize this so that the sample sentence is enclosed by double quotation marks, has no empty line before and after itself, and the term in sentence is replaced by the hyphen. All that change while keeping the tab after the term, the new line in the beginning of each term, and the only a space between the definition and the example sentence. I need this format for importing it to flashcards web application.

Desired outcome using above example:

```
exacerbate  worsen "This attack will – the already tense relations between the two communities"
exasperate  irritate, vex "he often – his mother with pranks"
execrable   very bad, abominable, utterly detestable "an – performance"
```

I am using Mac. I know basic command lines (including regex) and python, but not enough to figure this out by myself. If you could help me, I am very grateful.

Comment: Between the definition and the example only a space is required? Or should there be a tab there?

Comment: Only a space between the definition and the example sentence. Thanks asking for the clarification. I'll update my question.

Comment: Could you show the original CSV format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal to the directory where you have the input file.
Save the following code in a `.py` file:

```
import sys
import string
import difflib
import itertools


with open(sys.argv[1]) as fobj:
    lines = fobj.read().split('\n\n')

with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out:
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        line1, example = lines[i:i + 2]
        words = [w.strip(string.punctuation).lower()
                 for w in example.split()]

        # if the target word is not in the example sentence,
        # we will find the most similar one
        target = line1.split('\t')[0]
        if target in words:
            most_similar = target
        else:
            most_similar = difflib.get_close_matches(target, words, 1)[0]
        new_example = example.replace(most_similar, '-')
        out.write('{} "{}"\n'.format(line1.strip(), new_example.strip()))
```

The program needs the input file name and the output file name as command line arguments. That is, execute from the terminal the following command:

```
$ python program.py input.txt output.txt
```

where `program.py` is the above program, `input.txt` is your input file, and `output.txt` is the file that will be created with the format you need.

---

I ran the program against the example you provided. I had manually add the tabs because in the question there are only spaces. This is the output produced by the program:

```
exacerbate  worsen "This attack will - the already tense relations between the two communities"
exasperate  irritate, vex "he often - his mother with pranks"
execrable   very bad, abominable, utterly detestable "an - performance"
```

The program correctly substitutes `exacerbates` with a dash in the second example, even though the word is `exacerbate`. I cannot guarantee that this technique will work for every word in your file without having the file.

Comment: Awesome! Your program executed beautifully and I was able to import the results to flashcards web application with no hassle. Thanks to you I can spend more time on memorizing vocabs :)

Comment: @Vincent I'm glad I could help! If you encounter a case in which the transformation wasn't correct please leave a comment so I can fix the program. Irregular verbs, for example, probably weren't replaced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily bullet-proof, but this script will do the job based on your example:

```
import sys
import re
input_file = sys.argv[1]


is_definition = True

current_entry = ""
current_definition = ""

for line in open(input_file, 'r'):
    line = line.strip()

    if line != "":
        if is_definition == True:
            is_definition = False

            [current_entry, current_definition] = line.split("\t")

        else:
            is_definition = True

            example = line

            print (current_entry + "\t" + current_definition + ' "' + re.sub(current_entry + r'\w*', "-", line) + '"')
```

output:

```
exacerbate  worsen "This attack will - the already tense relations between the two communities"
exasperate  irritate, vex "he often - his mother with pranks"
execrable   very bad, abominable, utterly detestable "an - performance"
```

The problem with our current approaches is that it won't work for irregular verbs like: "go - went" or "bring - brought" or "seek - sought".

Comment: But I have got the same output as the post example.

Comment: Nope, check the second one.

Comment: Ahh, so you don't want the conjugation.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I noticed the difference between your output and the one in the question.

Comment: Yeah, irregular verbs are really a problem. I don't think there's a way around them without a table of irregular verbs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
suffixList = ["s", "ed", "es", "ing"] #et cetera
file = vocab.read()
file.split("\n")

vocab_words = [file[i] for i in range(0, len(file)-2, 4)]
vocab_defs = [file[i] for i in range(2, len(file), 4)]

for defCount in range(len(vocab_defs)):
    vocab_defs[defCount] = "\"" + vocab_defs[defCount] + "\""

newFileText = ""
for count in range(len(vocab_words)):
    vocab_defs[count] = vocab_defs[count].replace(vocab_words[count].split(" ")[0], "-")
    for i in suffixList:
        vocab_defs[count] = vocab_defs[count].replace("-%s" % i, "-")
    newFileText += vocab_words[count]
    newFileText += "  "
    newFileText += vocab_defs[count]
    newFileText += "\n"

new_vocab_file.write(newFileText)
```

Outputs:

```
============== RESTART: /Users/chervjay/Documents/thingy.py ==============
exacerbate  worsen  "This attack will - the already tense relations between the two communities"
exasperate  irritate, vex  "he often - his mother with pranks"
execrable   very bad, abominable, utterly detestable  "an - performance"

>>>
```

Comment: You have to replace the word with a dash in the example.

Comment: Thanks for noticing!

Comment: But now it has the same problem as @dgg32's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import re

with open('yourFile.csv', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()    

print(re.sub(r'(^[A-Za-z]+)\t(.+)\n\n(.+)\1[s|ed|es|ing]*(.+)$',r'\1\t\2 "\3-\4"', data, flags = re.MULTILINE))
```

Output:

> exacerbate    worsen "This attack will - the already tense relations between the two communities"
>
> exasperate irritate, vex "he often - his mother with pranks"
>
> execrable  very bad, abominable, utterly detestable "an - performance"